# Accessibility voice over starts reading content from the top of a page after clicking on a tooltip

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a tooltip link given on my webpage ( almost at the middle ). While doing accessibility testing, it starts reading the whole content from the top of the page again after clicking on the tooltip.

Is it default behaviour ? OR Can someone suggest a work around for this ?

I wanted to enable a continuity even after clicking / opening a tooltip.

Comment: What's a tooltip?  It can't mean using the `title` attribute of an element to display some additional data, because those are not clickable.

Comment: A tooltip is a link, onClick on it which renders a help text box

Comment: Do you have some HTML?  If the link has an href like "#" I can possibly see the reader starting over.  Perhaps `href='javascript:void(0)'` would work if so but that's a guess.

Comment: Just imagine the code is written in react. `<p onClick={this.toggleToolTip}>Some text</p> .    this.state.isToolTipEnabled && <div>Some Content</div>`

Comment: @James The focus is moving out from the pop-up box after clicking on the tooltip link & which is falling back to the top of the page. This might be the reason why the screen reader starts reading the contents from top. Don't you think so ?

Comment: I don't know without seeing the code/markup for your tooltip elements.

Comment: Please update your question and post the code in the question instead of in the comments.

Comment: Tooltips aren't clickable. By the sound of it, you have a clickable element which reveals extra content when clicked.  That's not a good use of a link element. You should use a button for this, not a link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if you are still facing this issue. I faced the same issue and after removing `role="alert"` on the `main/container` div resolved the issue.